# EtherWallet to Etherscan

Tags: myetherwallet

Seems that my EtherWallet Private Key takes me to a different account that doesn't show my correct Etherscan/Private EtherWallet address in Acct. Info. It instead shows my AION address (happened when I tried to use the AION Bridge two days ago) as my unencrypted Private Key address. I can still access my Etherscan using a URL address I stored and it has my correct "public address". How do I now transfer my Etherscan coins to a different EtherWallet or gain access to my original EtherWallet?

Comment: What does "Network" says in the top right corner? It should say "ETH". You can try MyCrypto (an alternative that forked from MyEtherWallet).

Comment: Yes it says ETH network.  Strange that I am getting logged into an Acct. with my AION Private Key showing.  I will MyCrypto a shot.  Still don't understand why my Etherscan acct. shows my original EtherWallet public address?  I thought that if you had your Private Password you could get back into your acct.?  The Etherscan acct. is still in tact (i.e. doesn't appear to be hacked).  Very strange indeed!!!

Comment: Tried MyCrypto - same result.  EtherWallet Private Key sends me to my new AION credentials.  How is that possible?  Etherscan with old Public address still accessible, but am I right in thinking without access to my Original EtherWallet account, they can't be moved?  Hopefully not!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct private key? What is your private key type? ie raw, json wallet, or seed phrase. I doubt that both MyCrypto and MyEtherWallet will show the wrong address, it is more likely you are using the wrong private key.

Comment: Wish that was the case.  Been using the same one for over a year.  Not a clue!?